# How does anacron work if it's not a daemon?

Tags: cron, background-process, anacron

I was reading about the differences between cron and anacron and I realized that anacron, unlike cron is not a daemon. So I'm wondering how does it work actually if it's not a daemon.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It uses a variety of methods to run:

- if the system is running systemd, it uses a systemd timer (in the Debian package, you’ll see it in `/lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer`);
- if the system isn’t running systemd, it uses a system cron job (in `/etc/cron.d/anacron`);
- in all cases it runs daily, weekly and monthly cron jobs (in `/etc/cron.{daily,weekly,monthly}/0anacron`);
- it also runs at boot (from `/etc/init.d/anacron` or its systemd unit).

Comment: I've seen the `{a,b,c}` notation around; can I use that in my shell? (I don't have access to it right now or I'd test.) Does it mean what it seems to -- that is, all files with the `{...}` replaced with any of the comma-separated things?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Bash (and a few other shells) expands braces in that way - see [Bash Reference Manual: Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 6):

`anacron` is not a daemon, and therefore it needs to be run periodically by other means.  Most often, this means executing it with a cron job once a day, and possibly on bootup as well.

This may look like the following in root's crontab, for example:

```
@reboot /usr/local/sbin/anacron -ds
@daily  /usr/local/sbin/anacron -ds
```

Linux systems that uses systemd may do this differently, obviously, but still need to facilitate at least one run of `anacron` per 24 hour period.

Running `anacron` more than once every 24 hours is pointless as the shortest period one can schedule jobs through `anacron` is once a day.

Comment: Thanks. (1) I was wondering what "not a daemon" means?  (2) regarding your last sentence: "The systemd timer runs anacron hourly to reduce the delay between resuming a suspended system and the next anacron run" https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478803/is-it-true-that-cron-daily-runs-anacron-everyhour/478842#comment875696_478842